# initialize a class object in the malloc address?

Tags: c++

say we have

```
Class A{};
int *p = malloc(100);
A a; //default constructor in use
*p = A; (question???)
```

how to initialize an object of type A on alloc memory p?

Comment: Read up on [_placement new_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new

Comment: Do not use `malloc` in C++.  Use `new char[100]` instead.

Comment: this is not what I wanted to do, this is an interview question:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To instantiate a class instance at a specific address you need to use [*placement new*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_new).

```
#include <new>
#include <stdlib.h>

class A
{};

int main()
{
  void *p = malloc(100);
  A* a = new(p) A();
  a->~A();  // call destructor explicitly
  free(p);
}
```

Note that the destructor must be invoked explicitly when using placement new.